# Wireless problem: I can't connect to any wifi even if I can see the SSID (Xubuntu 22.04LTS)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, xubuntu, network-manager

I just installed Xubuntu 22.04. Everything works fine except Wi-Fi.
I managed to connect with a cable and did all the software updates, but the problem still remains. When I try to connect to my access point I can see the SSID as in this screenshot, but when I try to connect the "disconnected" banner appears and I cannot access the web.

[image: as in this screenshot]

I've also tried to connect to a different network, but it is the same.
I've tried to check drivers: everything is up-to-date and there are no additional drivers available.
Furthermore I've tried to reinstall everything, but nothing changed.

You can find the output of `wireless-info` [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/H2y4XCgZMg/).

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Try in terminal `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off` and see if you can connect.  However one error in the scrippt result may be an issue with the router `bad VHT capabilities, disabling VHT`

Comment: Thank you very much! @Jeremy31: I tried to execute the command, but the problem persist. The output is empty, is it normal?

Comment: @waltinator: thank you very much for the answer, I already try to look at NetworkManager logs, but I only see that the connection fails. I've uploaded logs here: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XnH2VW48my/. Do you see any anomalies? Thanks again!

Comment: Seep the conversatiom about "secrets" - the `indra` wireless network wants "secrets", and you have supplied some. Your connection's state cycles `state: scanning -> authenticating`, `state: authenticating -> disconnected`, `state: disconnected -> scanning`, so I guess your network password is wrong, or you're using the wrong security (WPAx).

Comment: @waltinator thank you for the answer! The network password is correct (I've checked it carefully) and all the settings (including WPA) are the same that in other Linux laptop that I regularly use. I'm thinking that maybe the card is broken (but before reinstall Linux, it worked perfectly) even if I can see Wi-Fi networks. It seems very strange to me. Do you know how can I check it? Thanks again!